# Why the spring ternary expression get reversed result?

Tags: java, spring, ternary-operator

I am learning Spring with the book Spring in Action 3rd edition.

I am reading up to the section about ternary expression inside SpEL:

it wrotes:

> What if you want a SpELexpression to evaluate to one value if a
>   condition is true and a different value otherwise? For example, let’s
>   say that Carl (the Instrumentalist from earlier) wants to play a piano
>   if the song is “Jingle Bells,” but he’ll play a saxo-phone otherwise.
>   In that case, you can use SpEL’s ternary (?:) operator:

```
 <property name="instrument"
 value="#{songSelector.selectSong()=='Jingle Bells'?piano:saxophone}"/>
```

> As you can see, SpEL’s ternary operator works the same as Java’s
>   ternary operator. In this case, the instrumentproperty will be wired
>   with a reference to the pianobean if the song selected is “Jingle
>   Bells.” Otherwise, it’ll be wired with the bean whose IDis saxophone.

I implement this with the following xml:

```
<bean id="kenny"
        class="com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist"
        p:song="Jingle Bells">
        <property name="instrument"
            value="#{kenny.song == 'Jingle Bells' ? piano:saxophone}"/>

    </bean>

<bean id="piano"
        class="com.springinaction.springidol.Piano" />
    <bean id="saxophone"
        class="com.springinaction.springidol.Saxophone" />
```

The output:

> Playing Jingle Bells:TOOT TOOT TOOT

This is incorrect, should be:

> Playing Jingle Bells:PLINK PLINK PINK

I have checked that the test are using the correct xml and getting the correct bean, and the instruments' sound is right. ( TOOT TOOT TOOT for saxophone and PLINK PLINK PINK for piano )

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is it JSP as it seems to be? Please tag as such, if such is a case.

Comment: no jsp, just pojo with spring and xml.

Comment: What if you convert from `p:song` to `<property name="song" value="Jingle Bells"/>`?

Comment: @EmilSit The result is identical.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you are trying to reference a property that has not yet set. Even though it is set "before" the reference in the ternary expression in the XML, it is likely that at the time that the SpEL expression is being evaluated, the property has not yet been set.  See for example [this question on Spring setter order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139301/spring-setter-method-order).

If `instrument` is set before `song` is set, the behavior you are seeing makes sense.

(You could add log statements to to your setters to determine the empirical calling order.)